# How use dagger2 AppModule abstraction

Tags: android, dependency-injection, factory, dagger-2

I want create a an interface for appModule like :

```
public interface IAppModule {

Context providesContext();
}
```

and i have a factory to return AppModule , like this :

```
public class AppModuleFactory {
private static IAppModule appModule;
public static IAppModule create(PusheApp app){
    if (appModule ==  null)
        appModule = new AppModule(app);
    return appModule;

}
}
```

but dagger doesn't work with this abstraction, and dagger must know the detail of implementation

I will be grateful if anyone can help

Comment: have you used @Provide in IAppModule.java ?

Comment: Modules must be classes or abstract classes, I think. Only components can be interfaces.

Comment: @AutonomousApps Modules can definitely be interfaces, but then you're limited to `@Binds` and `@ContributesAndroidInjector` etc. Newer versions of Java (and newer desugaring for Android) can handle static methods on interfaces, which puts static `@Provides` methods back into the picture too.

Comment: Happy to be proven wrong about that! (I wish there were an example of a `@Module interface` anywhere in the [docs](https://google.github.io/dagger/), though). Btw, you don't need static methods on interfaces to use `@Provides` methods. You can use an abstract class with a companion object, and then use `@Provides @JvmStatic fun provideThing() ...`

Comment: I just double-checked the thing you said about static methods on interfaces. Despite what the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support) say, you can't do that below SDK 24. So that's a huge caveat to using interfaces instead of abstract classes.

Comment: @AutonomousApps You can find interfaces Module [in the FAQ](https://google.github.io/dagger/faq#what-do-i-do-instead), and in the code [on the InterfaceModule test](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/javatests/dagger/functional/binds/InterfaceModule.java). For desugaring, the docs you linked have "Default and static interface methods" listed with compatible `minSdkVersion` of "Any." under ["Supported Java 8 language features"](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#supported-features). You said "despite" that; do you have another source, or are you having trouble?

Comment: Android Studio warned me I needed minSDK 24 for static interface methods. And my app also wouldn't compile. HOWEVER, I did only try in Kotlin code and it's possible than vanilla Java would be a different story.

Comment: @AutonomousApps The problem is exactly Kotlin: Note from the doc that in addition to requiring the Android plugin of 3.0.0 or better, Android Studio only desugars files that go through `javac`. Kotlin files enter with the "third party plugins", which happens _after desugaring_; Kotlin files are not desugared. Please do not extrapolate your Kotlin experience to infer that the documentation is wrong or that Java static methods on Java interfaces are unavailable for minSDK <24.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I shall complain to the appropriate authorities.